# Accessing video stream from Looxcie device

Tags: android, bluetooth, mediarecorder

I'm looking to see if there's a way to get the audio and video streaming in from the bluetooth connection in an android app that I'd create.

http://www.looxcie.com/index.php/companion-apps/looxciecam

Looxcie has their own app which saves their video to a file, but I'd want access to the raw video stream using MediaRecorder if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Any success to connection your android device with looxice via bluetooth for video streaming ? I also tried this. it connect to looxice device via bluetooth and sending byte[] continuesly. And if i store it in file for later playing it, then it doesn't play at all.

Comment: Excuse me for possible irrelevance of my question by this moment, but I seemed like looxcie doesn't stream video via Bluetooth, but use 3G, 4G or Wi-fi instead, do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Looxcie device lacks in technical information that could help a developer to use it in a custom application. My advice is that first to check what Bluetooth profiles are available on that device and maybe there is VDP - Video Distribution Profile, A2DP - Advanced Audio Distribution Profile and AVRCP - Audio/Video Remote Control Profile.

But from what I know on Android you have only A2DP and no VDP. So, probably they send data over SPP - Serial Port Profile and reconstruct it on Android. If they work this way, is nothing you can do, it's like a proprietary format. You could ask Looxcie for more information about the device, they look like a friendly/enthusiastic open company and maybe they will share information.

A trick you could make is use that file feature, and have it like a virtual file that goes into your MediaRecorder. Again it may not work, it's possible that they don't write all the time, but periodically put chunks of data.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the info.  I sent an email to them first, but never heard back.  Time for a follow up :)

Comment: @Adam http://looxcie.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83 They say that they don't have any developer API/SDK.

Comment: @Adam http://looxcie.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/78/related/1 I think that this could be an work-arround for your problem: Accessing the LooxcieMoments Circular/Looping Video Buffer. You could keep monitoring this buffer.

Comment: @Adam Keep us updated with your progress sounds interesting, and frankly also Looxcie device it's interesting too.

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you've been able to figure anything out. What's the latest on accessing the Looxie programmatically @Adam?

Comment: we ended up moving away from Looxcie, but have had success with the GoPros that have wifi communications.